# How to connect to either Metamask or Coinbase wallet?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, coinbase-api, metamask, alchemy

How do you specify connection with Coinbase Wallet and Metamask separately?

Right now when using window.ethereum.enable() both the Metamask and Coinbase Wallet extensions popup. I would like two separate buttons, one for Metamask and the other for Coinbase Wallet.

My code:

```
const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3");
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(alchemyKey);

export const connectWallet = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) { //check if Metamask is installed 
      try {
            const address = await window.ethereum.enable(); //connect Metamask
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: Did you resolve it? I am trying get the same behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this discussion](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/8990#issuecomment-658985565), it seems like you may be able to use a different Metamask request method to force connection selection:

```
  const connectWallet = async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) { //check if Metamask is installed 
      try {
        const address = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: 'wallet_requestPermissions',
          params: [{ eth_accounts: {}}]
        }); 
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }
```

The `wallet_requestPermissions` seems to do the trick.

Comment: do you know how to get signer and provider info from this method? @thatguyintech

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was finding MetaMask provider and setting it as `window.ethereum.selectedProvider` - the solution taken from [this answer](https://github.com/Uniswap/web3-react/issues/300#issuecomment-995170556).

```
const {ethereum} = window;
const metamaskProvider = ethereum?.providers?.find(p => p.isMetaMask);

if (metamaskProvider && typeof ethereum.setSelectedProvider === 'function') {
  ethereum.setSelectedProvider(metamaskProvider);
}
```

Setting `ethereum.selectedProvider = metamaskProvider` directly **doesn't** work properly.

Note that `providers` and `selectedProvider` are there only with both Metamask and Coinbase Wallet installed, with either of them only installed it's different.